# C# synchronize wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

I have a project at school to make a WPF project which makes encryption and decryption of an input text. I want the application to be responsive but it always freeze.

I want to use TPL and I use TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() but it is not working. I don't want to use Dispatcher or something else what is specific only to WPF.

```
tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
int lineCount = textBoxInput.LineCount;
string encryptTextInput = "";

List<string> listText = new List<string>();
List<Task> listTask = new List<Task>();

var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

for (int cnt = 0; cnt < lineCount; cnt++)
{
    encryptTextInput = textBoxInput.GetLineText(cnt);
    listText.Add(encryptTextInput);
}

for (int cnt = 0; cnt < lineCount; cnt++)
{
    int line = cnt;

    var myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(result =>
    {  
        return EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(listText[line]);
    }, tokenSource.Token);
    listTask.Add(myTask);

    var display = myTask.ContinueWith(resultTask =>
    textBoxOutput.Text += myTask.Result.ToString(), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, ui);

    var displayCancel = myTask.ContinueWith(resultTask => 
    textBoxOutput.Text += myTask.Result.ToString(), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled, ui);               
}
```

Comment: If your encryption function is freezing the application, you might need to use  [multi-threading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm) so you can run the UI updates at the same time.

Comment: If  you want your application to be 'responsive' then first you need to eliminate running 2 loops in a row!  If nothing else cutting your string utilization in half will surely help.  Secondly since your encryption is inline you may be overthinking it trying to use TPL.  KISS -- Keep It Simple, Stupid.  Just do the straight encryption first then see If you need to consider multithreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactored method which relates to Encryption. Please, see the comments related to the code below:

```
 private async void buttonEncrypt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string elapsedTime = string.Empty;
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        int lineCount = textBoxInput.LineCount;
        var outputResult = String.Empty;

        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < lineCount; cnt++)
        {
            var lineToProcess = textBoxInput.GetLineText(cnt);

            //Code inside task will work in thread from thread pool, so the UI thread shouldn't be blocked
            string result = await Task.Run(() => 
                EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(lineToProcess), tokenSource.Token);

            outputResult += result;

        }

        //UI thread: when completed update the UI with encrypted text.  
        textBoxOutput.Text = outputResult;

        stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        time.Content = elapsedTime;
    }
```

A couple of comments related to the code above.
The code working in the following way:

1. Read lines from textbox line by line.
2. Processes each line one by one
   (in thread pool context) in order the lines are in input
3. When processing of all lines completed, add the result of encryption to the
   output textbox

The problem in previous code was that the UI thread was accessing too frequently and this lead to UI freezing during processing.

Now the processing is going in background thread and rendered on UI only when all processing completes.

Also, I recommend you to add some kind of indicator to inform the user that the input is processing: progress bar or something other.

Comment: It is a click event on a button, when i press the button i want to encrypt my text from a TextBox and i want to display on another TextBox. I have tried to encrypt all the text from TextBox at once and it didn't freeze while the encryption took place, but after displaying the text my application freeze completely. I need to take all text from TextBox line by line before encryption.

Comment: It seems that the problem could be not related to the code in the question. Could you please zip the code if it's not secure or something and send it to me. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried your application and it seems working fine for me. Could you please provide more details or steps of how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Well you need to enter a large text, if the text is not long you can't see it because the encryption is executed quickly. I need to make it synchronized for small and large text. Maybe the problem is how I get the text and how I send it to the encryption?

Comment: Please, see my updated answer above. Let me know if you have any more questions.